Remove duplicate lines from 2 files
i have 2 text files as a.txt  and b.txt containing single column data.  I want to remove the identical data from both the files using bash script.
For e.g
a.txt  contains data as below
a.b.c.com
c.d.e.com
f.g.h.com

and b.txt contains data as below
i.j.k.com
f.g.h.com

The output should be
a.b.c.com
c.d.e.com
i.j.k.com

I have tried with sort, uniq -u and so on.. But none of them gave me correct output.
sort a.txt b.txt | uniq -u

awk '!a[$0]++'  a.txt b.txt

This is not similar to question How to remove duplicate lines in a file? as i need to remove identical line completely. I don't need even one occurence of it. For.eg f.g.h.com is removed completely in above reference,.

Try awk '{a[$1]++; n[NR]=$1} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){if(a[n[i]]<2){print n[i]}}}' a.txt b.txt Not using the associative array directly because now it keeps the order of items intact.

sort a.txt b.txt | uniq -u does exactly what you want; if it doesn't work then you might have some CRLF or some hidden blanks in the files

What should happen for line which is present in only one file, but more than once?

Using any awk:
$ awk '{cnt[$0]++} END{for (i in cnt) if (cnt[i] == 1) print i}' a.txt b.txt
c.d.e.com
i.j.k.com
a.b.c.com

or sort+uniq+awk:
$ sort a.txt b.txt | uniq -c | awk '$1==1{sub(/ +[^ ]+ /,""); print}'
a.b.c.com
c.d.e.com
i.j.k.com

I'm assuming you don't care about the order of the output lines but if you do then edit your question to state how they should be ordered.

sort a.txt b.txt | uniq -u does the same thing

@oguzismail you should post that as an answer BUT The OP in their question said they tried it so idk...

OP has tried using sort so I take this to mean we do not need to maintain the original ordering of rows.
With sorted data we can make use of comm to filter out rows that exist in both files:
$ comm -3 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
a.b.c.com
c.d.e.com
        i.j.k.com

We can then pipe to sed to remove the leading tab (\t) for those rows that are unique to b.txt:
$ comm -3 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt) | sed 's/^\t//'
a.b.c.com
c.d.e.com
i.j.k.com

NOTE: this solution assumes duplicate lines are true duplicates, ie, the duplicate lines contain the same amount of (trailing) white space and the same line endings

There might be some CRLF or leading/trailing blanks in the files, try stripping them:
#!/bin/bash

sed -e $'s/\r$//; s/^[[:space:]]*/; s/[[:space:]]*$//' a.txt b.txt |
sort -b |
uniq -u

output:
a.b.c.com
c.d.e.com
i.j.k.com

